# Dynamic query and sql injects

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that receives a string parameter "OrderByColumn" and builds dynamic query accordingly.
This is the part of my stored procedure code:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN @OrderByColumn='Date' AND @OrderDirection=0 THEN tbl_Docs.Date END ASC,
  CASE WHEN @OrderByColumn='Count' AND @OrderDirection=0 THEN tbl_Docs.Count END ASC,
```

And in my code behind function that calls the stores procedure I have:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderByColumn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = orderByColumn;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderDirection", SqlDbType.Int).Value = orderDirection;
```

The user sets the OrderByColumn parameter by clicking on the gridviews column header, so there is no direct user input, so as I see there is no option to inject any thing...

In the book they also validate the orderByColumn string, I don't understand why it's needed because as I've noted the user can't input direct expression.

My question is:

is it safe?

I've also read in some book that ORDER BY clause doesn't support the use of parameters.
What does it mean?

Comment: The final part of your question around `ORDER BY` is that you have to explicitly define the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems safe enough to use.

Im not completely following this section

> I've also read in some book that ORDER
>   BY clause doesn't support the use of
>   parameters.

Do you mean the ORDER (ASC/DESC) or column?

If you are refering to the column, you can achieve this. Something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 3
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3, 1

DECLARE @FieldNumber INT

SELECT @FieldNumber = 1

SELECT *
FROM    @Table
ORdER BY 
            CASE @FieldNumber 
                WHEN 1 THEN ID
                WHEN 2 THEN Val
            END

SELECT @FieldNumber = 2

SELECT *
FROM    @Table
ORdER BY 
            CASE @FieldNumber 
                WHEN 1 THEN ID
                WHEN 2 THEN Val
            END
```

Comment: If I do "case" as you did I won't be able to add:  ASC/DESC, at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

**is it safe?**
Yes, that seems fine. The value is not being concatenated into an SQL string to then be executed, plus you are actually validating to explicitly checking for certain, valid values.

**I've also read in some book that ORDER BY clause doesn't support the use of parameters.
What does it mean?**
That means you can't do (e.g.) "ORDER BY @SomeVariable" where @SomeVariable is the column to order by. Hence you need to use a CASE approach like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is not just confined to SqlInjection attacks, there could many other reason why one should validate input.

`Parameters` are treated similarly as in `OVER` clause, as `constant` and is ignored. so It is not basically the matter of support for parameters, but the results you get, which are unaffected by the use

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it's safe as well... The contents of the parameter are not being directly included in the query being issued by the stored procedure - you are merely testing the param to decide what to put in the query yourself.

I think you can have a clear conscience...